# What is the best way to create a random value?

Tags: java, random

I am triying to create random value for my game to show enemies  on screen. BUt it some times shows 2 together some times 3 ...I want to ask that which is the best  formul for creating random value.. This is my so far random value

```
 random = 1 * (int) (Math.random() * 100);
```

Comment: @Meko: but do you *really* want (pseudo)random? To end users, sometimes "fake random" gives a better "random illusion" than true random. So you *may* want to discard, for example, the pseudo-random value given back in *random* that are too close to the *lastrandom* (that you'd keep track of).  For example, three ennemies all popping on screen randomly at (173,173) is possible (altough unlikely) but the user may prefer it if your game had a safety net preventing the "next random" from being less than 20 pixels from the last random value...

Answer (score 5):

*"BUt it some times shows 2 together some times 3"*

Given perfectly random numbers... In every 100 random values from 0 to 99, you'll find an average of 1.0 doubles.  A triple will occur on average once for every 10,000 values.  Given 10 million random numbers, java.util.Random yeilds the following results on my machine:

```
Doubles: 99873
Triples: 985

Double Rate: 1 in 100
Triple Rate: 1 in 10152
```

Source code:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Random;

public class Sandbox {
    public static final int NUM_ITERATIONS = 10000000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int cur;
        int last = -1;
        int secondLast = -2;
        int nDoubles = 0;
        int nTriples = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++) {
            cur = rand.nextInt(100);
            if (cur == last) {
                nDoubles++;
                if (cur == secondLast) nTriples++;
            }
            secondLast = last;
            last = cur;
        }

        out.println("Doubles: " + nDoubles);
        out.println("Triples: " + nTriples);
        out.println();
        out.println("Double Rate: 1 in " + Math.round(1.0 * NUM_ITERATIONS / nDoubles));
        out.println("Triple Rate: 1 in " + Math.round(1.0 * NUM_ITERATIONS / nTriples));

        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually the creation of genuinely random random numbers is a complex game in its own right. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) article on this subject will give you an insight into the complexity that lies therein. Simple approximations such as those outlined above are probably sufficient for game purposes but will, it should be noted, be inclined to be 'streaky' from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`java.util.Random`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

```
Random random = new Random(); // uses System.nanoTime() as seed
int enemies = random.nextInt(100);
```

Anyway, your approach is also fine, as it is in fact equivalent (behind the scene) with the above.

You can print a sequence of 100 random numbers generated your way and see for yourself that there isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you use if perfectly fine.

In case you want something simplier you might like to use [Random](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class like this:

```
Random generator = new Random(seed);
int number = generator.nextInt(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

...and sometimes 77, sometimes 23, etc, as expected in a [uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(discrete))?

If you would like a [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) instead for your "enemies", so that extremes are less likely, it [seems to be there in Java](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian()).